# Define Variable with Function

Tags: javascript

I need help explanation of this script

```
var test = {
    property_1 : 'aaa',
    property_2 : 'bbb'
}

var place = function(str, ph){
    return test[ph];
}
```

What is the meaning of definition `place` and what will be return type of that function?
I can't understand from where is parameter `str` and `ph` come?

Here is the screenshot tutorial i read that do this at **line 19**

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the meaning of definition `place`?

Functions are first class in JavaScript. They can be assigned as values for variables.

You can then invoke that variable `place`, which will invoke the function it points to (its value).

> What will be return type of that function?

In could be anything. Most likely it will be a `string` or `undefined`.

> I can't understand from where is parameter `str` and `ph` come?

They would be passed like so...

```
place(1, 2);
```

In your example, the first argument seems to be superflous as it's not used in the function's body.

Comment: i'm sorry. i can't understand what you mean. Did you mean declaration variable `place` above is not valid?

Comment: I added screenshot tutorial that do this. but still can't wondering where is the parameter passed like your example.

Comment: @GusDeCooL: The `place` declaration is perfectly valid. You can assign functions to variables (`var func = function() {...};`) the same way as you can assign other values to variables, such as strings, arrays, etc (`var someString = "foo";`). It's the same thing. `func` points to a function and `someString` points to a string. Maybe you find it helpful the read the MDN JS guide about functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions.

Answer (score 2):

`place` is a function. Its return type is `typeof test[ph]`, which is a `string`. It's *similar* to the following:

```
function place (str, ph) {
  return test[ph];
}
```

The parameters `str` and `ph` need to be passed to the function when you invoke it:

```
place("foo", "property_1");
```

**EDIT**: The second argument of [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can be a function. Thus, when you call `html.replace(searchPattern, placeholderReplacer)`, internally, `replace` will invoke `placeholderReplacer` with the parameters `str` and `ph`, which represent the matched substring, and the first matched capturing group, respectively.

#### References:

- [`JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: I wouldn't say strictly the *equivalent*. I'd say they are *similar*.